# Error: Ads SDK was initialized without an application ID

Tags: ios, xcode13.3

Error Xcode13.3 Ads SDK
without an application ID

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can work around it by adding the key-value pair in the documentation linked above to your Info.plist file.

### Successful Answer

1. Open your `info.plist` file and put that line:
2. `key = GADIsAdManagerApp`
3. `value = true`

Follow Image

[image]